# SSLPeerUnverifiedException (Unirest)

Tags: java, https, ssl-certificate, unirest

I'm new to messing around with APIs (both official and unofficial) and I'm using one called [JavaSnap](https://github.com/hatboysam/JavaSnap). I've  been messing around with a very basic implementation of the example code, but have been running into errors. Here is the very basic code:

```
Snapchat snapchat = Snapchat.login("xxxx", "xxxxx");
```

Firstly I ran into loads of ClassNotFound errors and had to keep on downloading apache modules (commons, httpcomponents etc.) to allow the program to progress, but being class files this meant I couldn't see all at once what modules I needed to download. So if anyone wants to tell me how wrong I'm doing something feel free.

Anyway, now having cleared up all the ClassNotFound exceptions (I hope) I'm getting the following exception:

```
com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name 'feelinsonice-hrd.appspot.com' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.appspot.com, O=Google Inc, L=Mountain View, ST=California, C=US)
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:146)
    at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:68)
    at com.habosa.javasnap.Snapchat.requestJson(Snapchat.java:953)
    at com.habosa.javasnap.Snapchat.login(Snapchat.java:160)
    at Tester.go(Tester.java:21)
```

As I understand it, this is because I need to enable trusting all certificates, however to do this I believe I'd need to use HostNameVerifiers with SSLSocketFactorys, but I can't really begin to mess around with this as I only have the source for the JavaSnap API, and tracing the error up the stack the most recent method available for me to edit is this:

```
private static HttpResponse<JsonNode> requestJson(String path, Map<String, Object> params, File file) throws UnirestException {
        MultipartBody req = prepareRequest(path, params, file);

        // Execute and return response as JSON
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> resp = req.asJson();

        // Record
        lastRequestPath = path;
        lastResponse = resp;
        lastResponseBodyClass = JsonNode.class;

        return resp;
```

My question is, am I actually on the right lines with my thinking? 
If I am how can I achieve my goal of eliminating this error / trusting certificates? If I'm not then what in fact is the problem?

Thanks very much

Comment: You should never trust arbitrary self-signed certificates. This is common and bad advice that has serious security implications. In this case you should obtain the certificate of the host you are calling and add it to your trust store with SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(). You can use keytool to create a keystore and import the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

i answer this old question to remember my search
the certificate error solution is a combination from a few places

- https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-java/issues/70, where i started.
- http://literatejava.com/networks/ignore-ssl-certificate-errors-apache-httpclient-4-4/ very good explanation.
- http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-ssl, solution for all versions.

---

```
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.security.cert.CertificateException;
import javax.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustSelfSignedStrategy;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;

import com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpResponse;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest;
import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;

public class XXX {

    private static HttpClient unsafeHttpClient;

    static {
        try {
            SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy() {
                public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    return true;
                }
            }).build();

            unsafeHttpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext)
                    .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier()).build();

        } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static HttpClient getClient() {
        return unsafeHttpClient;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            HttpClient creepyClient = RestUnirestClient.getClient();
            Unirest.setHttpClient(creepyClient);

            HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("https://httpbin.org/get?show_env=1").asJson();
            System.out.println(response.getBody().toString());

        } catch (UnirestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Trusting self-signed is okay for testing only. This will open users of your code to man-in-the-middle attacks and provide no defence. This is not even okay between services in an internal network, because it facilitates an attacker pivoting through weak internal defences. If you can't get a trusted CA (including your own) to sign the destination service, then you should obtain the certificate of the destination service and add it to your truststore with loadTrustMaterial().

Comment: yes i understand the security concern here. it means to be a quick test - you have no control on the server side, nothing more than that.